# How do I recursively run "chgrp" without changing the group if it matches a specific group?

Tags: files, directory, group, recursive, chgrp

I just copied all the files/subdirectories in my home directory to another user's home directory.

Then I did a recursive `chown` on his home directory, so that he became the owner of all his files/subdirectories.

The last thing I need to do is a recursive `chgrp` on his home directory, so that his username will be the group for all his files/subdirectories, instead of my username.

The issue is that there are a couple of subdirectories whose group is "docker". Inside these subdirectories, there are some files/directories whose group is my username, and some other files/directories whose group is "docker".

How do I recursively run `chgrp` on his home directory so that every single file/subdirectory whose group is my username gets changed to his username, but every single file/subdirectory whose group is "docker" stays "docker"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `find` to exclude anything owned by group `docker`; starting from the target home directory:

```
find . ! -group docker -exec chgrp newgroup {} +
```

replacing `newgroup` as appropriate.

Alternatively, look for anything owned by your group:

```
find . -group oldgroup -exec chgrp newgroup {} +
```

replacing `oldgroup` and `newgroup` as appropriate.

Comment: +1 Personally, I prefer the alternate.  Specify the exact group you want to search for and replace it with the other.

Comment: @JimL. Yeah, I used the alternate in case there was another group that I didn't see that should stay the same.

Answer (score 6):

> How do I recursively run (…) so that every single file/subdirectory whose (…) is (…)

The generic answer to this is either [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/index.html) or [zsh globs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation). Use one of these to enumerate the files you want to affect, and the `chgrp` you already know to act on those files (not in recursive mode, since find or zsh took care of the recursion).

```
find /home/new-user/some-files -group pacoverflow -exec chgrp new-user {} +
```

Or, if you're using zsh:

```
chgrp new-user /home/new-user/some-files/**/*(g:pacoverflow:)
```

The zsh solution may run into a command line length limit, in which case you can use [zargs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zargs) (similar to `xargs` or to `find`'s `-exec … {} +`)

```
autoload zargs
zargs -- /home/new-user/some-files/**/*(g:pacoverflow:) -- chgrp new-user
```

or the [zsh loadable built-in for chgrp](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002ffiles-Module)

```
zmodload -m -F zsh/files b:zf_\*
zf_chgrp new-user /home/new-user/some-files/**/*(g:pacoverflow:)
```

Comment: `zf_chgrp` also has the advantage of avoiding a separate process for `chgrp`, which does little more than wrap a system call.